# How to create a module from the test file

Tags: python

Am a Newbie in programming world learning to code in Python These test code below has given me problem trying to code the module itself,Please any help on how to code it will be highly appreciated.

```
from nose.tools import *
from glass import moviy


def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                      ('direction', 'south'),
                      ('direction', 'east')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("go"), [('verb', 'go')])
    result = lexicon.scan("go kill eat")
    assert_equal(result, [('verb', 'go'),
                      ('verb', 'kill'),
                      ('verb', 'eat')])

def test_stops():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("the"), [('stop', 'the')])
    result = lexicon.scan("the in of")
    assert_equal(result, [('stop', 'the'),
                      ('stop', 'in'),
                      ('stop', 'of')])


def test_nouns():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("bear"), [('noun', 'bear')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                      ('noun', 'princess')])

def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
    result = lexicon.scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                      ('number', 91234)])


def test_errors():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                      ('error', 'IAS'),
                      ('noun', 'princess')])
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a dictionary?

Comment: Do you mean Python Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You have a black box and by the inputs you must discover what it has inside.

This is the basic idea behind [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)

Like Ignacio said, you can use a dictionary. It will pass the test. But its no a very usefull implementation since you can't have a key for all numbers, for example.
It will do the trick. But will not work in real life.

Based in your tests, you have a lexicon object.

```
class Lexicon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass  
    def scan(self, inputStr):
```

You note that all returns are a vector of tuples. Each tuple is word in the input string.
So you can assume it is splited by space.

```
tokens = inputStr.split(" ")
```

Create a vector to save the answers:

```
answers = []
```

And you can start guessing from for each token.

```
for token in tokens:
```

Lets first try if it's a number.

```
try:
   answers.append(("number", int(token)))
except:
   pass
```

And in the end you return the answers

```
return answers
```

After this you can run the numbers test:

```
lexicon = Lexicon()
test_numbers()
```

And no error will happen.

After this you can test for strings in lists.
First create the lists in the object.

```
class Lexicon(object):
    directions = [ "north", "south", "east", "west"]
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

And in the scan function you test if the token is in the directions list.

```
...
pass
if token in self.directions:
    answers.append(("direction",token))
```

Now run:

```
lexicon = Lexicon()
test_numbers()
test_directions()
```

And no erros will happen !
The idea is similar to the others values.

By the way. If you don't have some concepts like class, tuple, dict. I sugest you take a look over [here](http://www.learnpython.org/)

Comment: Answer much Appreciated,Now what i want to understand is in the below code;                                                                   class Room(object):

        def __init__(self, name, description):
            self.name = name
            self.description = description
            self.paths = {}
  
        def go(self, direction):
            return self.paths.get(direction)

        def add_paths(self, paths): 
            self.paths.update(paths)

Comment: the Code you asked for is a class definition

Comment: the __init__(self, ... ) is the method called when you instantiate ( makes the class, a type, became a object, a variable ).

Comment: the self is the variable where all stuff related to your object are stored ,attributes[variables] and methods[functions]

Comment: But now what is the relationship between __init__ funtion and scan funtion in that lexicon class?

Comment: The __init__ method is the constructor. It will do whatever inicialization the lexicon Object needs. The scan method is called from the lexicon object constructed by the __init__, using the parameters you gave ( none in this case).

Comment: I suggest you take a time to learn some Oriented Object concepts. The diference between class and object, method and function, variable and attribute. Maybe this can be of help: http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/oops.html

Comment: These code aren't working with the test file please,